# IContextMenu::QueryContextMenu being called, but IContextMenu::InvokeCommand doesn't

Tags: c++, windows, com, atl, com-server

In my implementation of [`IContextMenu`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776095%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#methods) COM server, the [`QueryContextMenu`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776097%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) gets called (can see it with logging) but [`InvokeCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776096%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) doesn't. Here is the `QueryContextMenu`:

```
HRESULT ContexMenuImp::QueryContextMenu(HMENU hmenu,UINT indexMenu,UINT idCmdFirst,
    UINT idCmdLast,UINT uFlags)
{
    if (uFlags & CMF_DEFAULTONLY) {
        // shouldn't handle this situation:
        LOG("IContextMenu::QueryContextMenu:    (...,CMF_DEFAULTONLY)");
        return MAKE_HRESULT(SEVERITY_SUCCESS,FACILITY_NULL,0);
    }else if (InsertMenuItem(hmenu,indexMenu,TRUE,&globals.menuItemInfo) == FALSE){
        // error occurred:
        LOG("IContextMenu::QueryContextMenu:    Error: %d",GetLastError());
        return MAKE_HRESULT(SEVERITY_SUCCESS,FACILITY_NULL,0);
    } else{
        // the desired situation: add item to the menu:
        LOG("IContextMenu::QueryContextMenu(hMenu,indexMenu:%u,idCmdFirst:%u,idCmdLast:%u,0x%x):    All set...",
            indexMenu,idCmdFirst,idCmdLast,uFlags);
        return MAKE_HRESULT(SEVERITY_SUCCESS,FACILITY_NULL,1/*handle only a single item*/);
    }
}
```

Any idea why ?

Comment: No idea. What does your code look like?

Comment: My psychic powers tell me that you returned S_OK instead of the required MAKE_HRESULT, or you added your menu items with the wrong ID.

Comment: @RaymondChen: bad intuition here :-) would be glad for additional attempts.

Comment: I think a blog was written about your question 2 years later: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130201-00/?p=5383! Apparently it was not emails but Stack Overflow question!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You forgot to honor the `idCmdFirst` when you inserted the menu.

```
globals.menuItemInfo.wID = idCmdFirst;
globals.menuItemInfo.fMask |= MIIM_ID;
```

(So I was right: You added your menu items with the wrong ID.)

Note that since each context menu may have a different ID, you should not use a global.

Comment: I missed that spot.. I hereby acknowledge your psychic skills ;-)